# How do I use single quotes inside single quotes?

Tags: php, html, quotes

Can anyone explain how to make this code work?

```
echo '<div id="panel1-under">Welcome <?php echo "$_SESSION['username']"; ?></div>';
```

I've tried removing the single quotes (`echo '<div id="panel1-under">Welcome <?php echo "$_SESSION[username]"; ?></div>';`), but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
echo "<div id=\"panel1-under\">Welcome ".$_SESSION['username']."</div>";
```

or

```
echo '<div id="panel1-under">Welcome '.$_SESSION['username'].'</div>';
```

Quick Explain :

- You don't have to reopen the  tags inside a echo String (" ... ")
- What I have done here is to pass the string *"Welcome "* concatenated to *$_SESSION['username']* and *""*  (what the . operator does)
- PHP is even smart enough to detect variables inside a PHP string and evaluate them :

  $variablename = "Andrew";

  echo "Hello $variablename, welcome ";

=> Hello Andrew, welcome

More infos : [PHP.net - echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

Comment: PHP will replace variables inside a PHP string IF the string is in double quotes or a Heredoc. This is an important distinction.

Comment: +1 It's so in the example but I haven't mentionned it explicitly ! thx

Comment: `echo "<div id=\"panel1-under\">Welcome {$_SESSION['username']}</div>";` Should also work?

Answer (score 9):

Inside single quotes, variable names aren't parsed like they are inside double-quotes. If you want to use single-quoted strings here, you'll need to use the *string concatenation* operator, `.`:

```
echo '<div id="panel1-under">Welcome <?php echo "'.$_SESSION['username'].'"; ?></div>';
```

By the way: the answer to the question in the title is that in order to use a literal single-quote inside a single-quoted string, you *escape* the single-quote using a backslash:

```
echo 'Here is a single-quote: \'';
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to concatenate your strings & variables.

```
echo '<div id="panel1-under">Welcome ' . $_SESSION['username'] . '</div>';
```

Answer (score 5):

Variable expansion doesn't work inside of single quotes. You can do either:

```
echo "<div id=\"panel1-under\">Welcome {$_SESSION['username']}</div>";
```

or

```
echo '<div id="panel1-under">Welcome ' . $_SESSION['username'] . '</div>';
```

Comment: Cool! +1. I didn't know you can use assocative arrays like in the first example, I was suspicious if it'd work and I tested it myself and it actually works, although I'll probably never use it that way...

Comment: The first example will bring up a warning like "undefined constant 'username', assuming 'username'". It's best to use the bracket syntax:`echo "<div id='panel1-under'>Welcome {$_SESSION['username']}</div>";

Comment: The {} method is also the only way to interpolate sub dimensions of a multimdimensional array inside a double-quoted string. echo "$a[b][c]" will ouput the equivalent of `$a[b] . "[c]"` (something like 'Array[c]'), as PHP's parser isn't greedy for dimensional references.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, to use the single quote inside a string that is using the single quote as delimiter, you just escape the single quote inside the string.

```php
echo 'That\'s all, folks';
```

It's not clear what the purpose of your code is, though.

```php
echo '<div id="panel1-under">Welcome <?php echo "$_SESSION['username']"; ?></div>';
```

As you are already using PHP code, `<?php echo` is not necessary. If you are trying to output the content of a session variable, you can use the following code.

```php
echo '<div id="panel1-under">Welcome ' . $_SESSION['username'] . '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
$data = $session['user'];
echo "a big string and $data   thats simple"
```

Comment: And how does it answer the question `How to use single quotes inside single quotes?`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use double or single quotes inside double quotes.

```
#Result: Hello "World" 's
$a = '"World"';   
echo "Hello $a 's";

#Result: Hello "World" 's    
echo "Hello \"World\" 's";
```

You can also use double or single quotes inside single quotes. (Not recommended when building SQL queries)

```
#Result: Hello World's "s
echo 'Hello World\'s "s';
```