# sql with $_SESSION inside. Get this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE)

Tags: php, html, css, sql

Single quotes inside single quotes in php, I don't know how to get the `$_SESSION` variable inside a string. 
Having issues with the formatting of this line.

I have been looking at multiple answers similar, but got none of them working:

[How do I use single quotes inside single quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383838/how-do-i-use-single-quotes-inside-single-quotes)

[syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE) in Insert statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29060560/syntax-error-unexpected-t-encapsed-and-whitespace-in-insert-statement)

`$sql = "INSERT INTO pushtable (uidUsers, pushAntall, pushDato, pushKlokkeslett) VALUES ('$_SESSION['uid']', '$pushAntall', '$pushDato', '$pushKlokkeslett')";`

**ERROR**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or
>   number (T_NUM_STRING)

Also tried:

`` $sql = "INSERT INTO `pushtable` (`uidUsers`, `pushAntall`, `pushDato`, `pushKlokkeslett`) VALUES ('{$_SESSION['uid']}', '$pushAntall', '$pushDato', '$pushKlokkeslett');"; ``

**ERROR**

> Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION

How can i solve this?

**-SOLVED-**

> $sql = "INSERT INTO pushtable (uidUsers, pushAntall, pushDato, pushKlokkeslett) VALUES ('"·$_SESSION['uid'] ."', '$pushAntall', '$pushDato', '$pushKlokkeslett')";

Comment: Well, you can always assign it to a variable first

Comment: @CarlBinalla I tried doing this: ```$username = $_SESSION['uid'];```. Did not work..

Comment: have you start the session?

Comment: so insert `$username` instead of `$_SESSION['uid']`

Comment: @Asphaug Elaborate **Did not work**. Did you received the same error? Did you actually replaced it with `$username`?

Comment: @KUMAR. Yup, i can do ```echo $_SESSION['uid'];``` and get the uid echoed into the html website. But the problem is the formatting f the line becouse of all the singel quotes.

Comment: One more thing ,I really suggest using a prepared statement

Comment: @CarlBinalla ```$username = $_SESSION['uid'];``` with the new line: ```$sql = "INSERT INTO `pushtable` (`uidUsers`, `pushAntall`, `pushDato`, `pushKlokkeslett`) VALUES ('$username', '$pushAntall', '$pushDato', '$pushKlokkeslett');";``` still throw error number 2.

Comment: @CarlBinalla, I dont really care about prepared statements since its just local testing, and this is not going online.

Comment: Look at my earlier comment. Posted it with accident and edited it now. @CarlBinalla

Comment: Well, did you try concatenating it instead?

Comment: Suddenly got it working. $sql = "INSERT INTO pushtable (uidUsers, pushAntall, pushDato, pushKlokkeslett) VALUES ('"·$_SESSION['uid'] ."', '$pushAntall', '$pushDato', '$pushKlokkeslett')"; did the trick. Thanks guys!

Answer (score -1):

An elegant solution is to use sprinf [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO pushtable (uidUsers, pushAntall, pushDato, 
pushKlokkeslett) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
$_SESSION['uid'],
$pushAntall,
$pushAntall,
$pushKlokkeslett
);
```

Or fix your code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO pushtable (uidUsers, pushAntall, pushDato, pushKlokkeslett) VALUES ('". $_SESSION['uid'] ."', '$pushAntall', '$pushDato', '$pushKlokkeslett')";
```

Also check [string operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: Went for the "fix your code" solution, still throws: **ERROR** >Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '·' (T_STRING) in

when i do

```$sql = "INSERT INTO pushtable (uidUsers, pushAntall, pushDato, pushKlokkeslett) VALUES ('"·$_SESSION['uid'] ."', '$pushAntall', '$pushDato', '$pushKlokkeslett')";```

Comment: And the sprinf still throws "Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION".

I can still echo the uid.

Comment: @Asphaug You are not using a `.` here -> `"·$`

Comment: @CarlBinalla Sorry. Replaced the wierd dot with a normal dot. ```$sql = "INSERT INTO pushtable (uidUsers, pushAntall, pushDato, pushKlokkeslett) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['uid'] ."', '$pushAntall', '$pushDato', '$pushKlokkeslett')";```

Still throws "Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in"

Comment: Suddenly got it working. ```$sql = "INSERT INTO pushtable (uidUsers, pushAntall, pushDato, pushKlokkeslett) VALUES ('"·$_SESSION['uid'] ."', '$pushAntall', '$pushDato', '$pushKlokkeslett')";``` did the trick. Thanks guys!

Comment: I editted the answer to replace · with . !